# Firefox versus Opera

Tags: browser, encoding

I am using Linux Mint 21.2 Cinnamon and have a question about browsers URL encoding.

When I navigate using Firefox 123.0 (64-bit) and go to a page having "special characters" and I copy the URL, I get a text like this :

> `https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaqu%C3%ADn_Costa`    {í as %C3%AD}
>
> or
>
> `https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C`   {%D1 ...}

When I navigate to the same pages using Opera 121.0, the URLs when copied look far better :

> `https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaquín_Costa`  {an accent on the "i"}
>
> or
>
> `https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=храпеть`  {russian characters displayed properly}

I prefer the Opera way of encoding, so my question is what is wrong in my Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

- Open [`about:config`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox) in *Firefox*. Accept any warning
- Copy `browser.urlbar.decodeURLsOnCopy` and paste into that page's Search bar.
- Double-click that setting to set it to `true`

That change takes place immediately. Below is the URL as copied  before, and after, that change.

```
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaqu%C3%ADn_Costa

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joaquín_Costa
```